# How to switch to zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have liked the bash shell that ships default with elementary OS very much. But I would like to change to zsh that is a superset of bash. But I have not found a great guide to switch to zsh or how to install it and use it.

I do have found a few bash install instructions but I don't know if they will work fine. Do I need something else?

- https://gist.github.com/asifkkhan/86cfa8e348f35c0e6302
- https://gist.github.com/mkalygin/b3e9de184d83a29a6cd0

Comment: I would suggest [oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#basic-installation), super awesome framework for zsh. ;)

Comment: The install instructions you mention are for oh-my-zsh, not for zsh.

Comment: After installing zsh you can also add the following line to your .zshrc file: builtin . /usr/share/pantheon-terminal/enable-zsh-completion-notifications || builtin true So that the pop up notifications still work when applications finish in the terminal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Run this: `sudo apt-get install zsh`
2. Verify where `zsh` is by typing `whereis zsh`.
3. Run `chsh` and it'll ask you to type in your password and to enter the new value. If you've verified that `zsh` is available on `/bin/zsh`, type it in.

**Warning:** Be very careful when typing the path, as an invalid path given to `chsh` could cause a lot of problems.

[image]

Final step: Re-login

Answer (score 8):

I switched yesterday to `zsh`, all I had to do, was

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

Close all your terminals afterwards and you are done.
You can customize your shell further with [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).